# R: Possible to include some "header" files?

Tags: r, header

I'm new to R and have a basic question. I want to save in a file some variables etc. which I use in several programs. Instead of pasting all the code in each program I want to include always the same file in each program. So if I change something in the Header file, the change takes place in all programs which use this header. How can I do something like this in R?

In my header I only want to define some variables used in all programs.

Comment: you can i) place those variables in your .Rprofile ; ii) define them in a R file that you `source()` in each study, or, alternatively, `save` and `load` the variables ; iii) write a basic package (it is trivial with `package.skeleton`) containing those variables and functions that you use often, and simply load the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make a R source file, e.g. `my_header.R` and use the function `source` to include all variables defined in this file in all your scripts. You can just include the file with `source('my_header.R')`. Does this help?